# How to create back button with parameters in Ionicframework

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I try to create a back button using $ionicNavBarDelegate.back() in my application, but it's cannot back with url parameters.

For example:

`/demo/services?query=exam`

when use `$ionicNavBarDelegate.back()` , the page redirect to `/domo/services` , the url parameter has gone.

How to use `$inoicNavBarDelegate.back()` with parameters, or how to create a back button with parameters.